# Is it possible to see Outlook from Office 365 in my Google Calendar?

Tags: google-calendar, office-365, outlook, outlook.com-calendar

I use Google Calendar as my main calendar but I'm now working at a company that uses the Microsoft Office 365 suit of apps. I like seeing all my calendars into one place so I can see whether I'm busy when someone asks, knowing what I have to do without having to open more than one app, etc.

Is it possible to see my Office 365 Outlook calendar in my Google Calendar? I mean on the web version of Google Calendar.

Answer (score 0):

On my Android's Calendar I observed merging multiple calendars, from Google account, yahoo account and from my work MS Exchange account too. So I presume it may also function with your Office 365 calendar.

Comment: I'm not trying to do it in Android though but on the web, in Google Calendar.

Comment: I updated the question to make this clear. Thank you though.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:
Synchronizing events between your Outlook Calendar and Google Calendar 
https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/4132258/synchronizing-events-between-your-outlook-calendar-and-google-calendar